# Consolidate data in several columns to group by unique value in another column

Tags: r, aggregate, summarize

I am hoping to consolidate data in several columns to group by unique value in another column.

| group_id | food_1 | food_2 | food_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 6 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 0 | 5 |

I would like it be consolidated so it is one row for each `group_id`.

Answer (score 3):

In base R we can use `aggregate`: With aggregate we can apply the `sum` function to each column groupwise:

```
aggregate(. ~ group_id, df, sum)
```

the `dplyr` equivalent would be:

```
library(dplyr) #>= 1.1.0
df %>% 
  summarise(across(starts_with("food"), ~sum(.)), .by = group_id)
```

```
  group_id food_1 food_2 food_3
1        1      1      2      6
2        2      2      1      5
```

Comment: Great answer (+1)! Just a bit of code golf, but could shorten the `dplyr` approach to `summarise(across(starts_with("food"), sum), .by = group_id)` - no need to call the formula annotation here (unless there is a preferred reason I dont know about, highly likely)

Comment: Thanks. you are right, here we do not need anonymous function because we do not use any arguments inside. Great tip!